# Background process, loading bar

Tags: node.js

Most server-side-scripting languages have an exec function ([node](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec), etc). This allows the programming language to interact with the shell.

I wish to use `exec()` in node.js to run large processes, things I used to do with AJAX requests in the browser. I would like a simple progress / loading bar to display to the user the progress.

I found out the hard way in the example below that the callback / asynchronous nature of the `exec` function will make this example take over 5 seconds to load.

What I want is some way to get the content of browser to be updated (ajax) with the current state of the execution like a loading bar. But I don't want the ran file to be dependent on the browser.

Any idea?

my route

```
exports.exec = function(req,res){
  // http://nodejs.org/api.html#_child_processes
  var sys = require('sys')
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  var child;
  child = exec("node exec/test.js", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    var o = {
      "error":error,
      "stdout":stdout,
      "stderr":stderr,
    };
    o = JSON.stringify(o);
    res.send(o);
  });
};
```

my test.js file

```
var sys = require('sys');

var count = 0;

var interval = setInterval(
    function(){
        sys.print('hello'+count);
        count++

        if(count == 5){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    },
1000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for this.
Here is a [demo app](https://github.com/dotcloud/socket.io-on-dotcloud) to get you started with socket.io

You emit an event for every 1% using socket.io, the browser listen to it and update a bar.

You can't use exec you need a streamed output.
Therefore you'd rather use [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process).

On the server.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    exec  = spawn('node exec/test.js');

exec.stdout.on('data', function (message) {
  socket.emit('process', message);
});
```

On the sub process:

```
console.log('10%')
// ...
console.log('20%')
// ...
console.log('30%')
```

If your sub process is a node script you could do something a lot more elegant.
Rather than having to talk with a stream stdout you could use the [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_cluster) module of node to send messages between the master and the slaves process.

I made a [fork](https://github.com/3on/socket.io-on-dotcloud) of the previous demo app adding a route /exec which demonstrate how to achieve this.

When I'll have more time I'll make another demo app, this is a quite interesting and educational test. Thanks for the idea :D.

Comment: Thanks I'm up on your demo now and deep in the socket.io doc. It's hard for me to believe that no one has done this yet. Is it possible in any of the other language? Would node.js and socket.io be best fit for this?

Comment: @ThomasReggi: You can do this in every language/platform that has a websocket implementation. Do some work, emit and event. Do more work, submit another event... In each sumission you can pass the processing status.

Comment: Thanks for developing your answer further. This is awesome. I appreciate the repo including express3 and socket.io.

Comment: I'm kind of confused to how you setup `exec.on`. I can barely understand the doc... `'ipc' - Create an IPC channel for passing messages/file descriptors between parent and child. A ChildProcess may have at most one IPC stdio file descriptor. Setting this option enables the ChildProcess.send() method. If the child writes JSON messages to this file descriptor, then this will trigger ChildProcess.on('message'). If the child is a Node.js program, then the presence of an IPC channel will enable process.send() and process.on('message').`

Comment: I made a quick and dirty example. https://github.com/3on/socket.io-on-dotcloud clone this fork /exec and voila.

Comment: This is awesome. I have so much to learn from this example, and I cant wait to delve deeper into socket.io. I have one last question, that is: Is it possible to make it so that when the user closes the browser window the process will continue going. I got this [error](https://gist.github.com/3461186) on closing the browser window. I just want to confirm that it is possible.

Comment: A simple `if(typeof(clouds[socket.id]) !== "undefined")` cleared that up. I am really, really excited for this. Thank you so so so so so much.

Comment: You are welcome. And btw the boiler plates are ready to push to dotCloud.com (free account let you try all your services but you can't scale them).